# Sliders episode: City surrounded by huge wave

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

I'm afraid i cant be very helpful here but when i was much younger i watched an episode of a tv series which i remember being Sliders but cant seem to find any episode of that show with this description.

The part i remember is the end of an episode where there is a preview of the next episode. The preview involved the protagonists (cant remember anything about them) finding themselves in a city where the surround horizon contained a wave larger than all of the buildings in the city which was closing in upon them. I remember the city being empty apart from just them.

I know this isn't much to go on, I remembered this for some reason the other day and was hoping to watch the full episode but browsing the descriptions for the episodes of sliders (which i was sure it was) i couldn't find anything of that description.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a **Sliders** episode that matches the description.

At the end of [**Summer of Love**](http://sliders.wikia.com/wiki/Summer_of_Love) they slide to the [Tsunami World](http://sliders.wikia.com/wiki/Tsunami_World):

> The divergence point of this world is unkown but whatever caused this tragedy was forseen early enough for the citizens of San Francisco to evacuate...
>
> [image: Tsunami World]
>
>    [image: Tsunami World] <sup>[[Source](http://www.sliders-dimension.de/Episoden/1/06ReiseDurchDasZeitloch.htm)]</sup>

The story continues at the beginning of the episode [**The Prince of Wails**](http://sliders.wikia.com/wiki/The_Prince_of_Wails).

> Despite being originally aired before hand, the presence of the *Tsunami World* suggests the events of this episode begin roughly fourty-eight minutes after the events of *Summer of Love*.
>
> [image: Prince of Wails] <sup>[[Source](http://www.sliders-dimension.de/Episoden/1/05DerKorrupteSheriff.htm)]</sup>

Comment: Nice catch on the Prince of Wails bit. I have seen Sliders through and through a dozen times and never noticed they were wearing the same clothes at the beginning of Prince of Wails that they left Summer of Love in (I went back and checked the episodes). It think their clothing being the same is hard enough evidence to turn the "suggestion" into fact.

Comment: What I want to know is how they managed to climb to the top of that building so fast without getting wet.

Comment: Also, Rembrant suggests at the beginning of Prince of Wails that the "polar ice caps must have melted."